# Vuejs router push does not refresh page if it is already openend

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-options-api

so i am working on a school project and when i try to load a view using `this.$router.push()`
it works fine, but if that view is already loaded it does not refresh it which is neccesary if i want to make api calls again.

how can i make it so it loads mounted again or an alternative solution.

code:

```
   mounted() {
     if (this.pokemonId >= 1){
       this.fetchData()
     } else {
       this.fetchDataAlternative()
     }
     this.fetchNames()
     this.getColor()
   },


   created() {
    if (this.$route.params >= 1){
      this.pokemonId = this.$route.params.query
      this.fetchData()
    } else {
      this.pokemonName = this.$route.params.query
      this.fetchDataAlternative()
    }
     this.fetchNames()
     this.getColor()
  }
```

Comment: Precise your question if you want to know more about. The router.push() is dynamic (principle of SPA) and is invoque the route and not reload all the url.
But if you want to refresh the path, use ```window.location.reload()```

Comment: okay thanks, and where should i put that line of code? in the view itself or where i call the router.push?

Comment: `useRouter().go(0)` should work. Alternatively, `useRouter().push(useRoute(), { replace: true })` or `useRouter().replace(useRoute)`. I'd say including how you navigate is sort of relevant for the question you're asking.

Comment: @RaphaelRlt, `window.location.reload()` does a full app refresh, which might be detrimental for user experience (losing scroll position, store and components state, etc...). If your suggestion was an answer, I'd definitely downvote it.

Comment: use a watcher on the $route.params to know when to fetch the data